# Colon after user in SFTP connection string

Tags: sftp

I've come across using a value separated by a colon after the user in a connection string, e.g. sftp user:**abc**@hostname. Can anyone tell me what it should do?

I haven't been able to figure it out by using it, and googling for it just turns up the use of a colon after the server to specify a path to cd to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in most URL formats, the part after username and colon in SFTP URL is a password.

```
[sftp://][user[:password]@]host
```

Though not all SFTP clients do support passwords in the URL.

Notably, the most widespread SFTP client, [OpenSSH `sftp`](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp), does not. The documentation for its `destination` command-line argument says:

> The destination may be specified either as `[user@]host[:path]` or as a URI in the form `sftp://[user@]host[:port][/path]`.

Comment: Thanks you for the response Martin. I still have a point of confusion though: I'm using OpenSSH and if I use my password after the colon it just seems to be ignored. Is that the expected behaviour with OpenSSH, or should it produce an error?

Comment: It should not be ignored (tested with latest OpenSSH) –  It should be treated as a part of a username –  If I do `ssh foo:bar@host` I get prompt `foo:bar@host's password:`

Comment: Oh of course, that makes sense. Thanks for the help, marked as Answered.